# Apache Flink: Sorting dataset and creating DataStream from multiple input files with Event times

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Currently, I am working on a project in which I have a CSV file that needs preprocessing before it is "stream processed". Therefore, I need to perform batch as well as stream processing. In detail, my `data.csv` file needs to be preprocessed and sorted on a particular field, which is going to work as the `EventTime` timestamp for the stream processing. The batch script below produces the preprocessed output:

```
final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
DataSet<Tuple3<Long, String, String>> compactData = env
    .readTextFile("data.csv")
    .flatMap(new RichFlatMapFunction<String, Tuple3<Long, String, String>>() {
      private CustomDelegate delegate;
      @Override
      public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        delegate = new CustomDelegate();
      }
      @Override
      public void flatMap(String s, Collector<Tuple3<Long, String, String>> out)
          throws Exception {
        Tuple3<Long, String, String> datum = delegate.deserializeRide(s);
        if (datum != null)
          out.collect(datum);
      }
    });
compactData.partitionByRange(0)
    .sortPartition(0, Order.ASCENDING)
    .writeAsCsv("output_dir", "\n", ",");
env.execute();
```

My default parallelism is 32 and when the batch script (above) concludes execution, the `output_dir` directory gets created and it contains 32 files.

**Question 1:** My question is whether those files are produced based on the global order. In essence, do the records in file 1 have smaller values compared to the records in file 2 (and so on.)? If no, how can I guarantee the previous or something equivalent?

As I mentioned above, I use the files in `output_dir` as input for my stream processing job, which is timestamped by the first field of the previous (i.e., `EventTime`). The code of the stream job is the following:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
// Phase 0: Collect input and create timestamps
DataStream<Tuple3<Long, String, Integer>> dataStream = env
    .readTextFile("output_dir")
    .map(new MapFunction<String, Tuple3<Long, String, Integer>>() {
      @Override
      public Tuple3<Long, String, Integer> map(String s) throws Exception {
        String[] tokens = s.split(",");
        return new Tuple3<Long, String, Integer>(Long.parseLong(tokens[0]),
            tokens[1] + "-" + tokens[2], 1);
      }
    })
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
        new AscendingTimestampExtractor<Tuple3<Long, String, Integer>>() {
          @Override
          public long extractAscendingTimestamp(Tuple3<Long, String, Integer> t) {
            return t.f0;
          }
        });
env.execute();
```

**Question 2:** I define as input the directory `output_dir`, which contains the files sorted on field 0. Will the records be parsed and placed on the data stream based on the ordering that I want (i.e., on their field 0). If no, I believe that I will have problems with assigning timestamps (right?)? Can I have the `DataStream` be read from multiple files (as I do now), or do I have to combine all files into one, and create the DataStream by reading all records serially from a single file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question 1**: My question is whether those files are produced based on the global order. In essence, do the records in file 1 have smaller values compared to the records in file 2 (and so on.)? If no, how can I guarantee the previous or something equivalent?

No. Since there 32 partitions, data in each partition is ordered. But the data order between different output files are not guaranteed. You can manually set the parallelism of sortPartition operator to 1 or implement your own Partitioner instead of hash partitioner.

> **Question 2**: I define as input the directory output_dir, which contains the files sorted on field 0. Will the records be parsed and placed on the data stream based on the ordering that I want (i.e., on their field 0). If no, I believe that I will have problems with assigning timestamps (right?)? Can I have the DataStream be read from multiple files (as I do now), or do I have to combine all files into one, and create the DataStream by reading all records serially from a single file?

Assuming that there are 32 output files, if your parallelism of streaming job is also 32, then each file will be consumed by one parallelism, all the data from the this input file will be processed based on the data order appeared in the file in current parallelism. But once you try to aggregate data from 32 parallelism or try to shuffle data, the order of the data is not sorted any more. If you wish the receiver to get the data globally sorted, you may have to put all data in one file, and process them with a streaming job with one parallelism.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Regarding Question 1, I followed your advice and produced the globally sorted data in a single file. Turning to Question 2, it seems that if I want the data to be processed based on the EventTime, then I am stuck to parallelism equal to 1. Am I getting this right?

Comment: @nick.katsip For questions 2, If you want all records to be processed strictly on the event time one by one, then the parallelism for the operator to process those records should be 1, and make sure the input records for this operator is also globally ordered. If the data set is not very large, just set the parallelism of batch job and streaming job to 1, the records are processed globally ordered.

Comment: Thank you again David for the comment. Apparently, on Flink 1.2 I have to use a `windowAll()` transformation and then use a parallelism of 1 to process my data based on the event-time order. Again, thank you for your answer and your comments.